# Solving the equation $(x+1)xy''+(x+2)y'-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution to the equation $(x+1)xy''+(x+2)y'-y=0$ given that one of the solutions is a polynomial.

Here's what I did: plugging in $y=Ax^2+Bx+C$ we find that $y_1=x+2$ solves the equation. Then we can try to find a solution of the form $y_2=y_1 z = (x+2) z$. From the original differential equation we obtain $z''+\left ( \frac{2}{x+2}+\frac{x+2}{x(x+1)} \right)z'=0$. Then we must do fraction decomposition and the substitution $w=z'$ so we obtain $w=\frac{x+1}{x^2 (x+1)^2}$. Then we need to integrate the function $\frac{x+1}{x^2 (x+1)^2}$ which requires fraction decomposition once again and we arrive at the result $z=-\frac{1}{2x(x+2)}$ which in turn gives us $y_2=-1/(2x)$.

Although I got the correct result I wonder whether there is a simpler way of arriving at this solution (avoiding so many fraction decompositions and integrations which I omitted here). Maybe there's some better substitution that will work?

Comment: For information, there would exist a systematic way to obtain the general solution. In fact, this differential equation can easily be put under the form of the standard  "hypergeometric differential equation" $$z(1-z){\frac {d^{2}w}{dz^{2}}}+\left[c-(a+b+1)z\right]{\frac {dw}{dz}}-ab\,w=0$$ with $a=-1, b=-1, c=2$. The solutions are linear combinations of the one you have found, $(x+2)$ and another one, which, generally, is not very simple. Exceptionnaly, we are in a case with a very simple second solution.

Comment: @JeanMarie - good to know, thank you.

Comment: I have forgotten to say that $\dfrac{x+2}{2}$ comes from the hypergeometric function$_2F_1(a,b,c,x)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $z=xy$, we have that
$$z'=y+xy'\\
z''=2y'+xy''$$
then the equation becomes
$$(x+1)z''-z'=0$$
whose solutions are
$$z=k(x^2+2x)+b$$
where $k,b\in \Bbb R$.
Therefore,
$$y=k(x+2)+{b\over x}$$

Comment: Felicitations, very witty. May I ask you how you have found this transformation ?

Comment: Well done ! $+1$

Comment: Because there're many $xy$ terms. I tried and it worked.

Comment: Great, thank you very much.